# TCL exec command loop Help (Cisco Router)

Tags: loops, tcl, exec, cisco

I'm attempting to continuously loop 2 commands to cause an LED to blink on my Cisco 891-F.

Here's what I have so far.  I am not familiar with looping using foreach.  There may be another way to do this but I'm not aware.  Any help would be great!

```
if {[catch {ios_config "service internal"} result]} { 
puts "Invalid Command 1" 
}

set a "test led system black"
set b "test led system green-solid"

foreach {a b} [list $a $b] {
exec $a
exec $b
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind google eventually saved me :)

```
if {[catch {ios_config "service internal"} result]} {
    puts "Invalid Command 1" 
}

set a ["test led system black"]
set b ["test led system green-solid"]

for {set x 0} {$x<20} {incr x} {
    exec $a
    exec $b
}
```

Comment: You could use `foreach x {1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20}`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the square bracket being used by you in your answer is a typo.

```
set a ["test led system black"]
set b ["test led system green-solid"]
```

**It is not a correct way to define variables**. `Tcl` will throw error for the same unless you have a proc named as `test led system black`.

Defining them with out square bracket is fine like how you did your question.

```
set a "test led system black"
set b "test led system green-solid"
```

Or you can use braces.

```
set a {test led system black}
set b {test led system green-solid}
```

Remember, enclosing it with braces will prevent any sort variable substitutions.

Apart from this, what you have given for looping the variables is fine.